# Laravel/Ajax sends encoded url

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

i am trying to submit a form to my controller using Ajax. At first it was working properly but after a some time, it sends two requests with the first one correct and the second one having an encoded url. below is the error in the console for the second one;

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 POST http://127.0.0.1:7800/%7B%7Burl(%22appointment/create%22)%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

if i check in the network i get response with the first one and this error for the second;

```
message: "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",…
```

Below is my bootstrap modal where my form is;

```
<div class="modal fade" id="appointment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title colors" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Make an Appointment With our Doctors</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="ajax_class_form">
      <div class="form-row">
        @csrf
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="appointment-name" class="col-form-label colors">Name*</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-custom input-xs" name="appointment-name" id="appointment-name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="appointment-number" class="col-form-label colors">Number*</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-custom input-xs" name="appointment-number" id="appointment-number">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="appointment-date" class="col-form-label colors">When*</label>
                    <input type="Date" class="form-control form-custom input-xs" name="appointment-date" id="appointment-date">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="appointment-sms" class="col-form-label colors">Message*</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control form-custom input-xs" name="appointment-sms" id="appointment-sms" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary add_button" id="appointment-request">Request</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my js;

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#appointment-request').click(function() {
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{url("appointment/create")}}',
                type: 'post',
                data: $('#ajax_class_form').serialize(),
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```

Here is the route

```
Route::post('/appointment/create', 'AppointmentsController@store')->name('appointmentCreate');
```

Lastly the controller function is here;

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $appointment = new Appointment([
            'name' => $request['appointment-name'],
            'number' => $request['appointment-number'],
            'date' => $request['appointment-date'],
            'message' => $request['appointment-sms']
        ]);
        $appointment->save();
        return response()->json([
            'msg' => 'Appointment Sent'
        ]);
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        throw $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

This is the error in the console. The first request is okay but the second one seems to be encoded, i don't know why....
[image: Check the image]

Comment: The script is inside a blade template?

Comment: its in the app.blade.php where i link all the contents and the modals

Comment: It doesn't seem to recognize curly braces. Try `$.ajax({
                url: '/appointment/create',
                type: 'post',
                data: $('#ajax_class_form').serialize(),
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            })`

Comment: issue please, still sending two requests

Comment: Pass `e` to function and add. `e.preventDefault();`  . Ie: `
$('#appointment-request').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
            //...
        })`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ if i put `e.preventDefault()` it just rends the encoded request only. the correct request is not sent...